# Appropriate HTTP Method for 'Single Read' REST API

Tags: java, rest, web-services, http

We have a REST API that reads and deletes the record from database and returns the read value back to the client, all in same call. We have exposed it using HTTP POST. Should this be exposed as HTTP GET? What will be the implications in terms of Caching in case we expose it as GET.

Comment: GET request is idempotent, but in this case, you are reading data and after reading data from the database. It means a user can not read the value next time.

Comment: Yes. That is the intention. It must be one time read only. If same record identifier is sent again it should return error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should keep in mind that one of the reasons that we care that a request is [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) or [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) is that [the network is unreliable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing).  Some non zero number of responses to the query are going to be lost, and what do you want to do about that?

A protocol where the client uses GET to request the resource, and then DELETE to acknowledge receipt, may be a more reliable choice than burning the resource on a single response.

> Should this be exposed as HTTP GET?

Perhaps.  I would not be overly concerned with the fact that the the second GET returns a different response than the first.  Safe/idempotent doesn't promise that the response will be the same every time, it just promises that the second request doesn't change the effects.

[DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5), for example, is idempotent, because deleting something twice is the same as deleting it once, even though you might return 200 to the first request and 404/410 to the second.

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that causes loss of property (money, BTW, is considered property for the
> sake of this definition).

I think the thing to pay attention to here is "loss of property".  What kind of damage does it cause if *generic* components think that GET means GET? and act accordingly (for example, by pre-fetching the resource, or by crawling the API).

But you definitely need to be thinking about the semantics -- are we reading the document, and the delete of the database record is a side effect?  or are we deleting the record, and receiving a last known representation as the response?

POST, of course, is also fine -- POST can mean anything.

> What will be the implications in terms of Caching in case we expose it as GET.

[RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) - I don't believe there are any particularly unusual implications.  You should be able to get the caching behavior you want by specifying the appropriate headers.

If I'm interpreting your use case correctly, then you may want to include a [private directive](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.6), for example.

Answer (score 0):

As per the above discussion, it looks like PUT request. You should not use GET as it is idempotent because the same data is not available for the second time call. POST is used to create a new resource. So it will be better to use PUT http method for this kind of requirement. Refer below the link for more details.

https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/